# How to localStorage set Item after setState?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, setstate

I want to set My 'ques' array to my 'questions' property of Product state ,and then set my Products state to an array and save it all after submitClick ; but when I hit submit eventhough the state changes but the questions array which is setStated in my Product state in local storage is empty;
I don't know why is that and what to do for it ..

here's my code :

```
else {
                setMessage(null)
                Products?
                    products=Products
                    :
                    products=[]

                ques.push(selected);

                console.log(ques)

                setProduct({
                    ...Product,
                    questions:[ques[0]]
                })

                products.push(Product)

                localStorage.setItem('products',JSON.stringify(products))

                //
                // props.history.push(`/${brandId}/${modelId}/${yearId}/${pieceId}/confirm`)
            }
```

here is my localStorage after submit :
[image: local storage after submit]

Answer (score 1):

update state is async, so once you call `setItem` the state is not updated yet.

you need to use `useEffect` to listen products state update as below:

```
useEffect(() => {
 localStorage.setItem('products',JSON.stringify(products))
}, [Product])
```